# DataGrid Date String Filter

Tags: c#, date, datagrid

Trying to get help with this issue im trying to find a specific Date in my Datagrid with a text box. The Dates are currently strings formatted as dd/MM/yyyy. In a date column. I have posted before but got no useful answers and the my question got buried. Nobody seems to have a answer they just avoid the subject. At current time i cannot have the dates as DateTime because of the rest of app is formatted.

Thanks

EDIT CODE :

```
public class ImagesInfo
{
    public string FileName { get; set; } //For Picture File Name
    public string Description { get; set; } //For the Description of the Picture
    public string Category { get; set; } //Category of Picture
    public  string Date { get; set; }//Date Taken of the Picture, format discussed in report.
    public string Comments { get; set; } //Comments for the picture     
}
```

Code i used when finding a category in the datagrid.

```
if (categoryFilterBox.Text == string.Empty)
{
    //used if nothing is in the filter box to avoid blanking
    var source = new BindingSource();
    source.DataSource = images;

    navigationGrid.DataSource = source;
}
else
{
    //making a new filtered list that includes the matching Categorys and binding it.
    string catFilter;
    try
    {
        catFilter = categoryFilterBox.Text;
        var filteredList = images.Where(item => item.Category == catFilter);
        var filterSource = new BindingSource();
        filterSource.DataSource = filteredList;
        navigationGrid.DataSource = filterSource;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Must be Words of Letters");
    }
}
```

Example of a Record being added to my list which is the source of the datagrid.

```
private void addRecord()
{
    var newImage = new ImagesInfo();//new instance

    newImage.FileName = fileNameTextBox.Text;
    newImage.Category = categoryComboBox.Text;

    //try catch for input of the date
    try
    {
        newImage.Date = dateTakenTextBox.Text;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Date Not Correct Format");
    }

    try
    {
         newImage.Description = descriptionTextBox.Text;
    }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Must user letters and words");
        }
        try
        {
            newImage.Comments = commentsTextBox.Text;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Must use letters and words");
        }

        images.Add(newImage);//Add instance to the main list

        if (editCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            //Binding the new updated list to the datagrid
            var source = new BindingSource();

            source.DataSource = images;

            navigationGrid.DataSource = source;

        }

    }
```

EDIT: How i would i have got it currently but it does not seem to work.

```
    if (startDate.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            var source = new BindingSource();

            source.DataSource = images;

            navigationGrid.DataSource = source;
        }
        else
        {
            string dateFilter = startDate.Text;

            var filteredList = images.Where(item => item.Date == dateFilter);

            var filterSource = new BindingSource();

            filterSource.DataSource = filteredList;

            navigationGrid.DataSource = filterSource;

        }
```

Comment: Would be better if we see your code. Please post it.

Comment: Code has been added if more is needed i can provide

Comment: One question, what's exactly the problem? I have gotten that you have an issue with the dates, which are strings. However, I have not gotten where you try to find a specific date ? Thanks

Comment: In the code i posted there is category filter, i would like the same for my Date column but as they are strings i do not know a way to do it, and would like help with the issue.

Comment: Added what i have but it is not working like the category filter, i assume because the string is numbers and it has "/" ?

Comment: @ChristosPaisios i have provided what you requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
DateTime temp;
// try to parse the provided string in order to convert it to datetime
// if the conversion succeeds, then build the dateFilter
if(DateTime.TryParse(TrystartDate.Text, out temp))
{
    string dateFilter = temp.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    var filteredList = images.Where(item => item.Date == dateFilter);
    var filterSource = new BindingSource();
    filterSource.DataSource = filteredList;
    navigationGrid.DataSource = filterSource;
}
```

Comment: this has the same effect as what i tried to refreshed the same datagrid, would it be better i used a different datatype not DateTime but int OR Double?

Comment: i don't think that this would help because the strings you have are dates. In other words, I don't see how it would work something like this.